# Maps alert not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-alarms

I am developing an app in android version 2 for maps.I am already able to display the map.Now I need my app to perform snooze for every 10 meters if my tracker crosses the destination marker for which i have set my alarm.How to do that?Please can anyone send me the source code.Please Help me out.I have tried with it but not able to perform snooze.

Comment: see this example..http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-and-removing-proximity-alert-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-locationmanager/

Comment: Nobody can send you source code only help you. So show your implemented code.

Comment: ya what you have implemented..,show your code..

Comment: I Have implemented the same proximity alert code... I am able to get that alerts . But my question is when my marker crosses the specified radius for which i have set my alarm it should perform snooze for every next 10 meter radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proximity alert to display say between source and destination and based on your requirement, do your stuff for every 10 meters. See this. Hope this might helps you.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-and-removing-proximity-alert-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-locationmanager/